# What are empty xml elements used for?

Tags: xml

is this true?
An empty XML element is an element with no textual context. An empty element also has no child elements. It can have attributes though.
It is represented using a start tag and an end tag with no text in between. It can be represented using an empty element tag as well. The empty element tag representation is preferred for interoperability.

What are its different usages? like what is it used for?

Answer (score 0):

to signify an empty value instead of doing something stupid like

```
<element>null</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples in HTML without attributes include `<hr/>` and `<br/>`. Examples with attributes include `<imc src="a.jpg"/>`. In data-oriented XML, an empty element such as `<mobile/>` is sometimes used in preference to omitting the element entirely when there is no known value.

A more sophisticated use is with "overlap" markup, to mark the beginning and/or end of a construct that spans nodes in the primary hierarchy; for example to mark the positions of page boundaries when the primary hierarchy represents sections and paragraphs.

You say: "The empty element tag representation is preferred for interoperability." Preferred by whom? Any conformant XML parser will accept both forms.